# bistable single push toggle using momentary pushbutton, NO contiguous toggle upon hold

Tags: arduino, toggle, gpio

How to stop contiguous state change upon button hold?

```
    const int btn = 5;
    const int ledPin = 3;
    int ledValue = LOW;

    void setup(){
        Serial.begin(9600);
        pinMode(btn, INPUT_PULLUP);
        pinMode(ledPin, OUTPUT);
    }

    void loop ()
    {
        if (digitalRead(btn) == LOW)
        delay(100);
    {
        ledValue = !ledValue;
        delay(100);
        digitalWrite(ledPin, ledValue);
        delay(100);    
        Serial.println(digitalRead(ledPin));  
      }
     }
```

When I hold the button I receive contiguous state change. I want to press button and receive single state change, upon hold -- or accidental hold -- I would not like to change state.

More looking for effect of edge detection with the result of flip flop.

There is more development to be done on this code but this is the first stage.
Eventually I will integrate a FOR statement into the loop and perhaps a SWITCH(case) statement.

Basically I need to be able to toggle output pins with a single momentary push, I also would like -- in the FUTURE -- to be able to cycle through possible output states based on specific input conditions, by way of using FOR and SWITCH(case) together. That is a different post. Unless you can surmise a solution for that problem as well.

Comment: when you push your button , it is connected to ground?

Comment: It is.

The button is from GND to PIN 2 

I am using a MEGA 2560 for prototyping.

Comment: There should be a simple way to compare the number of states. If the number of state changes is greater than 1, no output change. Like an exclusive-or (^). That would be ideal. Not (!), works to flip flop but I would expect that (^) would result in a single state change until button press again. Simply because the output is an exclusive result of one state or the other. Using the (!) operator may simply cause the state to flip-flop outside of delay times. In a loop, I might suppose that the (!) operator would do exactly that, cause a continuous bi-stable state change.

Comment: I have no idea what I'm saying. It just sounds right.

Comment: I have an easier time expressing these ideas in English than in computer language. I know what I want to do, just don't quite see how to get there.

Comment: If you want to detect **CHANGE**, you may use **interrupt**. These links may help: https://playground.arduino.cc/Main/PinChangeInterrupt and http://playground.arduino.cc/Code/Interrupts .

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way is to add a variable that holds the state of the button.

When you press the button, that variable is set to true and the code you want runs. While that variable is true, the code you wrote will not be executed a second time. When you release the button, the variable gets set to false, so a next button press will have your code executed again.

Code:

```
bool isPressed = false; // the button is currently not pressed

void loop ()
{
    if (digitalRead(btn) == LOW) //button is pressed
    {
       if (!isPressed) //the button was not pressed on the previous loop (!isPressed means isPressed == FALSE)
       {
         isPressed = true; //set to true, so this code will not run while button remains pressed
         ledValue = !ledValue;
         digitalWrite(ledPin, ledValue); 
         Serial.println(digitalRead(ledPin));  
       }
    }
    else
    {
       isPressed = false; 
       // the button is not pressed right now, 
       // so set isPressed to false, so next button press will be handled correctly
    }
 }
```

Edit: added a second example

```
const int btn = 5;
const int ledPin = 3;
int ledValue = LOW;
boolean isPressed = false; 

void setup(){
    Serial.begin(9600);
    pinMode(btn, INPUT_PULLUP);
    pinMode(ledPin, OUTPUT);
}

void loop ()
{
  if (digitalRead(btn) == LOW && isPressed == false ) //button is pressed AND this is the first digitalRead() that the button is pressed
  {
    isPressed = true;  //set to true, so this code will not run again until button released
    doMyCode(); // a call to a separate function that holds your code
  } else if (digitalRead(btn) == HIGH)
  {
    isPressed = false; //button is released, variable reset
  }
}

void doMyCode() {
  ledValue = !ledValue;
  digitalWrite(ledPin, ledValue); 
  Serial.println(digitalRead(ledPin));
}
```

Comment: From what I gather, though...this is exactly the style of code I am looking for. I like this.

Comment: So !isPressed must be true for digitalWrite(ledPin, HIGH)? 

...and !isPressed is essentially the same as digitalRead(btn, LOW)

When those conditions are met, isPressed then becomes TRUE which flips the output value at the ledPin...?

Comment: I think your getting it half. The variable isPressed creates a second condition that must be met before *your code*. isPressed is set / reset when the button status **changes**. That is the first loop, 'the first moment' that the button is pressed / released. That makes that the *your code* happens only once per button press. I added a second example - fully the same principle - that maybe makes things more clear. Just try it on your arduino.

Comment: `ledValue = !ledValue;` is the right way to toggle the LED. So when the button is pressed, the ledValue flips only once, and the new value is used in digitalWrite() which changes the LED status. You where right there

Comment: What is confusing me is that digitalRead(btn) is already initially LOW just like isPressed is initially false. So what is the first IF statement calling to? Those conditions are preset as default initial values. If int ledValue = 0, it might make more sense.

Comment: if (!isPressed) //the button was not pressed on the previous loop (!isPressed means isPressed == FALSE)

That makes no sense to me.

isPressed is initially defined as FALSE so how is !isPressed == FALSE as well. !isPressed would give the inverted value of isPressed which should be TRUE. Is it a typo in the notes?

because the code works...

At any rate I like your code better. It makes more sense.

Comment: `!isPressed` is shorthard for `isPressed == false` Note the ! only being in the first statement. I should have added quotes. digitalRead(btn) is **not** initially LOW, it read the pin when you call the function and returns the state, whichs id HIGH or LOW. Because you defined the pinMode as INPUT_PULLUP, it means that when the arduino reads the pin it returns HIGH when the button is not pressed. Read more about that [here](https://www.arduino.cc/en/Tutorial/DigitalPins)