# Using switch to select a case with pushbutton -- toggle

Tags: arduino, switch-statement, toggle, increment, gpio

I am working on a toggle using switch case. Not sure if I'm doing it right. My intention should be fairly obvious through my code example.

I want to increment a counter with a pushbutton use the x++ function and some toggle code I have saved that should be usable in a switch(case) statement to produce desired outcomes at a particular case by toggling an output pin on upon case selection and off when case is no longer valid. Each case would have its own output pin with a specific case loop to execute when that case becomes valid. I can write the output loops once I get the toggle mode working. There are some missing pieces to the code. I have no formal coding experience and have only taught myself a little bit here and there. I've started with my Basic Stamp Homework Board and switched over from BS2 to Arduino. My goal is to compile the codes that I need for basic projects and save it. Then I can realistically be done with base-coding and focus on connecting hardware and fine-tuning the hardware:software.

Not quite sure how to use this switch function. Wondering if I need to have a FOR statement somewhere in there to increment my counter. Was thinking I could increment the counter each time the toggle1 value flipped or something to that effect. Another though would be to utilize switch(case) by modulo, toggling case values by pressing the button a specific number of times. 1 press would be case 1, 2 press -- case 2, 3 press -- case 3, etc... Case 0 could be 5  presses and be the last cycle using the ++x operator. Toggling case using pushbutton and ++ should be a very very simple matter. I have very little experience with programming. Would like some guidance. I hope that the gist of my idea is all in the code. Thank you.

```
const int btn = 22;
const int led = 3;
int selector1 = i;
int btnValue = digitalRead(btn);
int i = 0;


bool isPressed = false;


if (btnValue == LOW && isPressed == false){
    i = i++;

    if (i > 3){
        i = 0;
    }
}

{
    switch(case){

        case 1:

        selector1 == 0;
        do digitalWrite(led, HIGH);
        Serial.println(digitalRead(23));
        break;

        case 2:

        selector1 == 1;
        do digitalWrite(13, HIGH);
        Serial.println(digitalRead(13));
        break;

        case 3:

        selector1 == 2; 

        do digitalWrite(4, HIGH);
        Serial.println(digitalRead(4));
        break;

        case 4:

        selector1 == 3

        do digitalWrite(5, HIGH);
        Serial.println("You've reached the last selection.");
        Serial.println(digitalRead(5));
    }
}
```

Comment: hi, I've edited your question to improve code formatting and reduce the text a bit; still it's quite long, so I recommend you to try to shorten it. The most important things are: what are you trying to achieve, what you have tried (your current code, see also [mcve]), how that failed. As a short note, you don't need an extra `{...}` wrapper *around* `switch(...){...}` thing

Answer (score 0):

What is your question exactly? Keep It Short and Simple ;) Also, have you tried google? [This](https://www.arduino.cc/reference/en/language/structure/control-structure/switchcase/) is the first hit using 'Arduino switch'. There are even examples ([one](https://www.arduino.cc/en/Tutorial/switchCase) [two](https://www.arduino.cc/en/Tutorial/SwitchCase2)) build into the arduino IDE. Searching and trying will teach you better than asking. Really, try things out - a lot. When you run into something new, like a switch-statement, upload a very easy sketch to the arduino and just test it out.

With that said, the main issue here seems to be that your code is very incomplete. Is this meant as testcode, or did you just copy some stuff to convey your idea? Because this code makes it very hard to help you in a clear and specific way. You also reintroduced the button pushdown issue from your [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53980861/bistable-single-push-toggle-using-momentary-pushbutton-no-contiguous-toggle-upo/53981747?noredirect=1#comment94803385_53981747) (that is still open).

For your edification I'll list a couple or the issues and also provide corrected code below

`i++;` suffices to increment `i`

`switch(case)` should be `switch(i)`

remove 'do' from `do digitalWrite()`

`selector1 == 1;` does nothing.

there is no main loop

`int selector1 = i;` this is initiating a variable with a variable that doesn't exist yet. This is pass by value, not a reference to i, so in your current code selector1 will never change.

`int btnValue = digitalRead(btn);` similarly, this is a one time assignment, it never changes

`digitalWrite(13, HIGH);
 Serial.println(digitalRead(13));` This is odd, though to my surprise not impossible. What are you trying to do here? Because it makes no sense to me.

Corrected code:

```
const int btn = 22;
const int led = 3;
int selector = 0;
boolean isPressed = false; 

void setup() {
  Serial.begin(9600);
  pinMode(btn, INPUT_PULLUP);
  pinMode(led, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(13, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(4, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(5, OUTPUT);
}

void loop ()
{
  if (digitalRead(btn) == LOW && isPressed == false ) //button is pressed AND this is the first digitalRead() that the button is pressed
  {
    isPressed = true;  //set to true, so this code will not run again until button released
    doSwitchStatement(); // a call to a separate function that performs the switch statement and subsequent evoked code

    selector++; // this is done after the doSwitchStatement(), so case 0 will be executed on the first button press 
    if (selector > 3) {
      selector = 0;
    }
    // selector = (selector+1) % 4;  // does the same, without if-statement
  } else if (digitalRead(btn) == HIGH)
  {
    isPressed = false; //button is released, variable reset
  }
}

void doSwitchStatement() {
  switch(selector) {
  case 0:
    digitalWrite(led, HIGH);
    Serial.println("Case 0");
    // add a call to doExtraStuff() if you like
    break;
  case 1:
    digitalWrite(13, HIGH);
    Serial.println("Case 1");
    break;
  case 2:
    digitalWrite(4, HIGH);
    Serial.println("Case 2");
    break;
  case 3:
    do digitalWrite(5, HIGH);
    Serial.println("You've reached the last selection.");
    Serial.println("Case 3");
  }
}
```

With each button press, first `doSwitchStatement()` is executed, which sets an outputpin high and prints a message. After that`selector` is incremented and set to 0 if it reaches 4.